# Correlation Matrix in Matrix Notation

Tags: matrices, statistics

The covariance matrix for a random vector X with size n is given by

E[(X-E(x))'(X-E(x))]

But what about for the correlation matrix? What is the matrix notation for a correlation matrix?

Is this even a thing?

Answer (score 1):

The correlation matrix is indeed a valid concept.

Let $\Sigma$ be the covariance matrix of a set of random variables **X** $=$ $X_1$, $X_2$,...., $X_n$.

(i.e.  $Cov(\bf{X})= \Sigma$).

We then have the correlation matrix given by 
$$Corr(\bf{X}) =  \left[diag\left(\Sigma\right)\right]^{-1/2} \Sigma\left[\text{diag}\left(\Sigma\right)\right]^{-1/2}$$

This provides a clean definition of the correlation matrix for a collection of random variables.